# Tradeoff between a LEO-LEO vs LEO-GEO data relay

Tags: low-earth-orbit, communication, geostationary, data-transmission

For both commercial and government entities alike, the need for reduced turnaround time in payload delivery (e.g. for optical or [synthetic aperture radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic-aperture_radar) images) has led to the development of data relay systems, where both mission tasking and payload downlink can be done outside of a ground station's communication cone.

On a LEO to GEO scale, we have NASA's [Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_Data_Relay_Satellite_System), ESA's [European Data Relay System (EDRS)](https://connectivity.esa.int/european-data-relay-satellite-system-edrs-overview) and more recently a commercial solution of [Intersatellite Data Relay System (IDRS)](https://www.idrsspace.com/). Are there any LEO to LEO solutions out there?

What are tradeoffs in using each?

Comment: genuine question that I worry will sound snarky: would Starlink meet your criteria of LEO-LEO data relay? I think it's illustrative of the tradeoffs, but want to make sure I'm thinking along the same lines you are before trying to write an answer based on that

Comment: @ErinAnne No worries at all. It’s a legitimate question, one I thought of as well before posting my question. Functionally, I haven’t seen starlink being used as a data relay with a third party LEO satellite. But as you said, it could be illustrative of the tradeoffs